# How to convert rows into columns without GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
greeting:
+-------------------------+
| id | lang_id | name     |
+-------------------------+
| 1  | 1       | 'Hello!' |
| 1  | 2       | '¡Hola!' |
| 1  | 3       | 'Salut!' |
+----+---------+----------+
```

I need to create a .CSV file out of it for subsequent processing:

```
greeting.csv:
---------------------
id;en;es;fr
1;Hello!;¡Hola!;Salut!
---------------------
```

I can select all languages as a row by using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT
    id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ';') as 'name'
FROM
    greeting
WHERE
    greeting.id = 1;
```

It produces the result:

```
id | name
---+--------------------
 1 | Hello!;¡Hola!;Salut!
```

However, it requires special processing of the 'name' column in code, since I have to tokenize the concatenated string before I can proceed.

I was wondering if there is a way to get result like this:

```
id | en     | es     | fr
---+--------+--------+-------
 1 | Hello! | ¡Hola! | Salut!
```

So I can process the columns in a uniform way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a [*pivot*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table), which isn't natively supported in mysql, but is easy enough to code:

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.name en,
  t2.name es,
  t3.name fr
FROM greeting t1
JOIN greeting t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.lang_id = 2
JOIN greeting t2 ON t1.id = t3.id AND t3.lang_id = 3
WHERE t1.lang_id = 1
AND t1.id = 1
```

You could leave off the final condition `t1.id = 1` to get *all* greetings.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I tried to solve it with joins, too, but I was getting all possible combinations of languages and id's because I forgot to specify the `AND t2.lang_id = 2` part. It looks more elegant than `MAX(CASE ...)`, so I'll accept your reply as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
  id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN lang_id=1 THEN name END) eng,
  MAX(CASE WHEN lang_id=2 THEN name END) es,
  MAX(CASE WHEN lang_id=3 THEN name END) fr
FROM
  yourtable
GROUP BY
  id
```